# How can I get the average of an array using a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters, average

**Quiz instruction**: 
Code a function that takes an array of numbers as a parameter and returns the average of them as the result.

Examples: `average([2,2,5,8])` returns `4.25`. `average([59,60,40])` returns `53`.

**Code so far**:

```
function average(array) {

    var denominator = array.length; 
    var numbers = array;

    for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var total = numbers[0] + numbers[1] + numbers[2];
    }

    var avg = total / denominator;
    return avg;
    console.log( avg );
}

average([1,2,3]);
```

//Returning error. Not sure where the mistake is. Also, what would the code be if you were to expand the array and still get the average, no matter the inputs in the array parameter. 
//Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Why is java tagged ?

Comment: Java is to JavaScript, what Car is to Carpet.

Comment: Hint: use `numbers[i]` to get the amount of the current element. If you add each of these to the cumulative number, then you have the total.

Comment: There is no (syntactical) error as far as I can see. "Returning error" is kinda vague ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip @MCEmperor, worked. Thanks Jonas / Sudhir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your average function;

```
function average(numbers) {
  let denominator = numbers.length;
  let sum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < denominator; i++) {
    sum = sum + numbers[i];
  }

  return sum / denominator;
}

console.log(average([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(average([2, 2, 5, 8]));
console.log(average([59, 60, 40]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
function average(nums) {
    return nums.reduce((a, b) => (a + b)) / nums.length;
}

average([1,2,3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let average = (array) => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length;
console.log(average([5,10,30]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below url for calculating sum. and then find average by dividing this sum amount with array.length

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce